# Ajax not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using Ajax  , but it doesn't work here is my Ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(event){
var ad1 = $("#ad1").val();
var ad2 = $("ad2").val();
var city = $("city").val();
var state = $("state").val();
var zip = $("zip").val();
var country = $("country").val();
var mm = $("mm").val();
var dd = $("dd").val();
var yy = $("yy").val();
var lname = $("lname").val();


// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&ad11='+ ad1 + '&ad21='+ ad2 + '&city1='+ city + '&state1='+ state + '&zip1='+ zip + '&country1='+ country + '&mm1='+ mm + '&yy1='+ yy + '&dd1='+ dd + '&lname1=';

        if(name=='')
        {
            alert("");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

and it's not giving any result just giving data in header

the result is like : [image]

---

I copied the javascript to the form page it's now working ,but the ajax is returning a blank alert while it should be **"Form Submitted Succesfully"**
I guess that it's an error of inclusion of the file , but i'm using the right directories.

---

here is **action.php** :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","db"); 

$name=$_POST['name1'];
$ad1=$_POST['ad11'];
$ad2=$_POST['ad21'];
$city=$_POST['city1'];
$state=$_POST['state1'];
$zip=$_POST['zip1'];
$country=$_POST['country1'];
$mm=$_POST['mm1'];
$dd=$_POST['dd1'];
$yy=$_POST['yy1'];
$dob=$dd."/".$mm."/".$yy;
$mm=$_POST['mm1'];
$name=$_POST['name1'];
$lname=$_POST['lname1'];


$r2=rand(10000,90000);

$query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into users values('$r2','$name','$lname','$ad1','$ad2','$city','$state','$zip','$country','$dob')");
mysqli_close($con);
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";

?>
```

---

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in your `click()` handler.

Comment: it gives the same result

Comment: Remove `return false` and add `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Looks like you're using a form (just a guess, it's impossible to tell without the accompanying HTML). Don't handle clicks, handle the *submit* event, eg `$('form-selector').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Can you explain please , how a form can't handle clicks ?

Comment: But i already used .val() in other forms , and it works good.

Comment: Like I said, it's impossible to tell without seeing the HTML but it looks like your form is submitting (via `method="GET"` which is the `<form>` default)

Comment: Your selectors are wrong for most of the `.val()` calls too (unless you have elements `<ad2>`, `<city>`, etc)

Comment: @Phil : Yeah , forgot to add the `#` but i fixed it .

Comment: @HMNFN You only fixed the first instance. All your fields have the same problem (missing `#` or `.`)

Comment: shouldn't the ajax `url` property be "action.php" not "ajaxsubmit.php"?

Answer (score 0):

This `name` variable is not have defined in ajax file `var dataString = 'name1='+ name +` so `name` would be an empty string

=> `if(name=='')
{
    alert("");
}` executed. Please add string into alert and check again :)